# Find surrounding the latitude and latitude values of given latitude and longitude(i.e: location) with specified radius using java program

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

All latitude and longitude values (including current location and other locations) are varchar datatype in mysql db table. I am struggling to get all maximum and minimum latitude/longitude values that are within 2km or 5km radius of current location. My current location latitude and longitude values and other location lat/long values are  stored into mysql db table using google map api.

I need to fetch the location records (max/min latitude/longitude values)which are all within given radius of current location  from table.

### Input :

Location : AA  (or) Lat: 12.561 and Lon : 77.48
Radius /Distance : 2km

### Table :

### Location |  Lat   |   Long

### AA      |  12.561  |   77.48

### A2       |      12.567 |  77.489

### A4     |         12.59  |  78.42

### A6    |           12.57  | 77.45

### Output :

List of Location name which is satisfied above condition.

It would be great help, if you will give few line of java code.

I need to get the o/p of lat/long values all direction (N/E/S/W) without using bearing value as my application don't have bearing value. It should get output values only using input of current location latitude /longitude and distance/radius value.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change coordinates from Varchar to DECIMAL(8, 6) to allow to calculate distance.

The following SQL query uses [**Spherical Law of Cosines**](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate the distance between a coordinate and coordinates in a table.

> d = acos( sin(φ1).sin(φ2) + cos(φ1).cos(φ2).cos(Δλ) ).R

The query uses [**MySQL Math functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html)

```
"SELECT Location,Lat,Long,(6367 * acos( cos( radians(center_lat) )
  * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( radians( Long ) - radians(center_long) )
  + sin( radians(center_lat) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM table 
  HAVING distance < radius ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20"
```

Where `center_lat` &`center_long` are coordinates of given point

PS use 3956 for miles 6367 for kms

Comment: Hello, is there a way to do this with Javascript only, iterating through an Array.? Thanks